# ¿Cómo crear una lista con datos de una tabla django?

Tags: html, python, django, django-models, django-forms

Estoy diseñando un proyecto en el cual se me requiere que ingrese los valores de un equipo, se coloca el nombre del equipo, el capitán y su escudo.

En otra tabla tengo que crear a los jugadores, pero se requiere que al momento de ingresar al jugador en su formulario HTML se muestre a que equipo va a ingresar, para que se muestre en una lista desplegable, es decir, que me debe mostrar los valores que he ingresado en mi tabla de equipos.

El formulario de ingreso de los equipos funciona perfectamente, pero no he logrado que en el formulario de ingreso de los jugadores me muestre a los equipos que he ingresado en forma de lista.

La vista `add_registro` permite ingresar los valores de los nuevos jugadores:

Archivo `views.py`:

```
def add_registro(request):

    equipo=DatosEquipo.objects.last()
    con = DatosOperador.objects.all() 
    form = UploadForm(data=request.POST, files=request.FILES)

    if request.method == 'POST':

        if form.is_valid():

            newdoc =  DatosOperador(fecharegistro=request.POST['fecharegistro'], eps=request.POST['eps'], telefono=request.POST['telefono'], numerodocumento=request.POST['numerodocumento'], alergias=request.POST['alergias'], rolequipo=request.POST['rolequipo'], estadosalud=request.POST['estadosalud'], fecha=request.POST['fecha'], nombreoperador = request.POST['nombreoperador'],apellidooperador = request.POST['apellidooperador'], tipodocumento=request.POST['tipodocumento'],  
                nombreacudiente=request.POST['nombreacudiente'], idacudiente=request.POST['idacudiente'], telefonoacudiente=request.POST['telefonoacudiente'], direccionacudiente=request.POST['direccionacudiente'], fotografia=request.FILES.get('fotografia'), equipo=equipo)
            newdoc.save(form)
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/ingreso')
        else:
            form=UploadForm()
    else:
        form = UploadForm(request.POST)

    args={}
    args['form']=UploadForm()
    return render(request, "ingreso.html", args, {'form':form,'con':con})
```

Archivo `models.py`:

```
def random_id(lenght=9):
    return ''.join(random.choice(string.letters + string.digits) for x in range(lenght))

class DatosEquipo(models.Model):

    ideq = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=9, default=random_id, editable=False)
    nombrecapitan=models.CharField(max_length=800, blank=False, null=False)
    nombreequipo=models.CharField(max_length=800, blank=False, null=False)
    escudo = models.ImageField(upload_to='escudo/%Y/%m/%d', null=True, blank=True)

class DatosOperador(models.Model):

    nombreoperador=models.CharField(max_length=800, blank=True, null=True)
    apellidooperador=models.CharField(max_length=800, blank=True, null=True)
    fecha = models.DateTimeField(['%Y-%m-%d'], blank=True, null=True)
    fechaf = models.DateTimeField(['%Y-%m-%d'], blank=True, null=True)
    fecharegistro = models.DateTimeField(['%Y-%m-%d'], blank=True, null=True)
    tipodocumento=models.CharField(max_length=30, choices=CHOICES1)
    fotografia = models.ImageField(upload_to='imgf/%Y/%m/%d', null=True, blank=True)
    estadosalud=models.CharField(max_length=800)
    rolequipo=models.CharField(max_length=800)
    alergias=models.CharField(max_length=800)
    telefono=models.CharField(max_length=800)
    numerodocumento=models.CharField(max_length=800)
    eps=models.CharField(max_length=800)
    nombreacudiente = models.CharField(max_length=800)
    idacudiente = models.CharField(max_length=800)
    telefonoacudiente = models.CharField(max_length=800)
    direccionacudiente = models.CharField(max_length=800)
    equipo=models.ForeignKey(DatosEquipo, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False, blank=False)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('nuevafecha', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

Archivo `forms.py`:

```
class UploadForm(forms.Form):
fecha=forms.DateField(label=("Start date"),
                                initial=datetime.now(),
                                input_formats=['%Y-%m-%d'],
                                widget=forms.DateInput(format = '%Y-%m-%d'), required=False)
fechaf = forms.DateField(label=("Start date"),
                                initial=timezone.now(),
                                input_formats=['%Y-%m-%d'],
                                widget=forms.DateInput(format = '%Y-%m-%d'), required=False)

fecharegistro = forms.DateField(label=("Start date"),
                                initial=datetime.now(),
                                input_formats=['%Y-%m-%d'],
                                widget=forms.DateInput(format = '%Y-%m-%d'), required=False)

nombreoperador = forms.CharField(max_length=100, required=False)
apellidooperador = forms.CharField(max_length=100, required=False)
alergias = forms.CharField(max_length=100, required=True)
tipodocumento=forms.ChoiceField(choices=CHOICES1, required=True)
estadosalud=forms.ChoiceField(choices=CHOICES2, required=True)
rolequipo=forms.ChoiceField(choices=CHOICES3, required=True)
telefono=forms.CharField(max_length=100, required=False)
numerodocumento=forms.CharField(max_length=100, required=False)
eps=forms.CharField(max_length=100, required=False)
nombreacudiente = forms.CharField(max_length=100, required=False)
idacudiente = forms.CharField(max_length=100, required=False)
telefonoacudiente = forms.CharField(max_length=100, required=False)
direccionacudiente = forms.CharField(max_length=100, required=False)
fotografia = forms.FileField(label='Selecciona una Fotografia', required=False)

class Meta:
    model=DatosOperador
    fecha=forms.DateField(input_formats=settings.DATE_INPUT_FORMATS )
    fields = '__all__'

class UploadForm1(forms.Form):
    nombrecapitan=forms.CharField(max_length=800, required=True)
    nombreequipo=forms.CharField(max_length=800, required=True)
    escudo = forms.FileField(label='Selecciona una Fotografia', required=True)

class Meta:
    model=DatosEquipo
    fields = '__all__'
```

Archivo `formulaio.html`:

```
<body>

<form action="{%  url 'registroop' %}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">{% csrf_token %}
<h1><a target="_blank"><p style="color:white;">MANEJO DE OPERADORES FCAT</p></a></h1>

<section id="uno">

    <div class="content">
        <div class="admin-panel"><label for="toggle" class="admin-text">INGRESO</label></div>
        <input type="checkbox" id="toggle">
        <label class="cog octicon octicon-gear" for="toggle"></label>
        <div class="menu">

            <div class="arrow" align="center"></div>

            <table class="table table-hover" align="center" border="1">        
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th><h2><p style="color:white;"><b>Nombre del Operador</b></p></h2></th>

                    <th><h2><p style="color:white;"><b>Apellido del Operador</b></p></h2></th>

                    <th><h2><p style="color:white;"><b>Tipo De Documento</b></p></h2></th>

                    <th><h2><p style="color:white;"><b>Numero De Documento</b></p></h2></th>
                </tr>

            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td><p align="center">{{ form.nombreoperador }}</p></td>

                    <td><p align="center">{{ form.apellidooperador }}</p></td>

                    <td><p align="center">{{ form.tipodocumento }}</p></td>

                    <td><p align="center">{{ form.numerodocumento }}</p></td>
                </tr>    

            </tbody>  

            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th><h2><p style="color:white;"><b>Nombre del Equipo</b></p></h2></th>

                    <th><h2><p style="color:white;"><b>Fecha De Ingreso al Equipo</b></p></h2></th>

                    <th><h2><p style="color:white;"><b>Rol Equipo</b></p></h2></th>

                    <th><h2><p style="color:white;"><b>Telefono</b></p></h2></th>
                </tr>

            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>

                    <td><p align="center">{{con.equipo.nombreequipo}}</p></td>
                    En esta parte es que se requiere que muestre la lista de los equipos ya creados 
                    <td><p align="center">{{form.fecha}}</p></td>                                           

                    <td><p align="center">{{ form.rolequipo }}</p></td>

                    <td><p align="center">{{ form.telefono }}</p></td>
                </tr> 
            </tbody>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th><h2><p style="color:white;"><b>Fecha de Registro</b></p></h2></th>

                    <th><h2><p style="color:white;"><b>EPS</b></p></h2></th>

                    <th><h2><p style="color:white;"><b>Estado de Salud</b></p></h2></th>

                    <th><h2><p style="color:white;"><b>Alergias</b></p></h2></th>

                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td><p align="center" >{{form.fecharegistro}}</p></td>

                    <td><p align="center" >{{form.eps}}</p></td>

                    <td><p align="center">{{ form.estadosalud }}</p></td>

                    <td><p align="center">{{ form.alergias }}</p></td>

                </tr>   
            </tbody>
             <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th><h2><p style="color:white;"><b>Nombre de Acudiente</b></p></h2></th>

                    <th><h2><p style="color:white;"><b>Nº Identificacion</b></p></h2></th>

                    <th><h2><p style="color:white;"><b>Telefono</b></p></h2></th>

                    <th><h2><p style="color:white;"><b>Direccion</b></p></h2></th>

                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td><p align="center" >{{form.nombreacudiente}}</p></td>

                    <td><p align="center" >{{form.idacudiente}}</p></td>

                    <td><p align="center">{{ form.telefonoacudiente}}</p></td>

                    <td><p align="center">{{ form.direccionacudiente}}</p></td>

                </tr>   
            </tbody>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th><h2><p style="color:white;"><b>Fotografia</b></p></h2></th>    
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td><p align="center">{{form.fotografia}}</p></td>
                </tr>   
            </tbody>

        </table>        

        </div>

        </br>
         </br>
         </div>
        <div class="content1">
            <input type="submit" value="Ingresar Operador"  onclick="clicked(event)" >
        </div>     
</section>  
</form>
```

Espero me puedan ayudar ya que es un problema que me tiene detenido en este proyecto.

Nuevo forms.py

```
    CHOICES1=[('cedula','Cedula'),('t.i','T.I'),('pasaporte','Pasaporte'),('cedula ext','Cedula de Extranjeria')]
CHOICES2=[('excelente','Excelente'),('bueno','Bueno'), ('regular','Regular'), ('malo','Malo') ]
CHOICES3=[('lider','Lider'),('comunicaciones','Comunicaciones'),('apoyo','Apoyo'),('reconocimeinto','Reconocimeinto'), ('francotirador','Francotirador'),('medico','Medico')]
CHOICES4=[(0),(0)]
ateInput=partial(forms.DateInput, {'class':'datepicker'})
time_widget = forms.widgets.TimeInput(attrs={'class': 'timepicker'})
valid_time_formats = ['%H:%M', '%I:%M%p', '%I:%M %p', '%H:%M %p', '%H:%M%p']


def lista():
    i=0
    for id1 in DatosEquipo.objects.all():

        if i==0:
            CHOICES4=[(id1.ideq,id1.nombreequipo)]
        else:
            CHOICES4=[(id1.ideq,id1.nombreequipo)]+ CHOICES4
            print CHOICES4
        i=i+1

    return CHOICES4

class UploadForm1(forms.Form):
    nombrecapitan=forms.CharField(max_length=800, required=True)
    nombreequipo=forms.CharField(max_length=800, required=True)
    ciudadequipo=forms.CharField(max_length=800, required=True)
    telefonoequipo=forms.CharField(max_length=800, required=True)
    escudo = forms.FileField(label='Selecciona una Fotografia', required=True)

    class Meta:
        model=DatosEquipo
        fields = '__all__'

class UploadForm(forms.Form):
    fecha=forms.DateField(label=("Start date"),
                                    initial=datetime.now(),
                                    input_formats=['%Y-%m-%d'],
                                    widget=forms.DateInput(format = '%Y-%m-%d'), required=True)

    fecharegistro = forms.DateField(label=("Start date"),
                                    initial=datetime.now(),
                                    input_formats=['%Y-%m-%d'],
                                    widget=forms.DateInput(format = '%Y-%m-%d'), required=True)

    nombreoperador = forms.CharField(max_length=100, required=True)
    apellidooperador = forms.CharField(max_length=100, required=True)
    alergias = forms.CharField(max_length=100, required=True)
    tipodocumento=forms.ChoiceField(choices=CHOICES1, required=True)
    estadosalud=forms.ChoiceField(choices=CHOICES2, required=True)
    rolequipo=forms.ChoiceField(choices=CHOICES3, required=True)
    CHOICES4=lista()
    nameequipo=forms.ChoiceField(choices=CHOICES4, required=True)
    telefono=forms.CharField(max_length=100, required=True)
    numerodocumento=forms.CharField(max_length=100, required=True)
    eps=forms.CharField(max_length=100, required=True)
    nombreacudiente = forms.CharField(max_length=100, required=True)
    idacudiente = forms.CharField(max_length=100, required=True)
    telefonoacudiente = forms.CharField(max_length=100, required=True)
    direccionacudiente = forms.CharField(max_length=100, required=True)
    fotografia = forms.FileField(label='Selecciona una Fotografia', required=True)

    class Meta:
        model=DatosOperador
        fecha=forms.DateField(input_formats=settings.DATE_INPUT_FORMATS )
        fields = '__all__'
```

Comment: Te debería aparecer en el form de los "jugadores", un `<select>`, en donde se listan los equipos creados. O quieres una lista "compleja" donde se muestre no solo el nombre del equipo si no los datos de los equipos?

Comment: no solo quiero una lista sencilla de los equipos creados nada mas para que el usuario seleccione a que equipo desea pertenecer nada mas

Comment: Por eso, acabo de ver tu template y estas mostrando mal el campo del listado de equipos, es asi que debes hacerlo: `{{ form.equipo }}`, no `{{ con.equipo.nombreequipo }}`. De esta manera te mostrara el select con la lista de los equipos para que los selecciones, recuerda reprensentar el objeto en cadena creando el metodo `__str__` en tu modelo.

Comment: Hola ya lo hice de esa forma y no me muestra nada en el template lo que e logrado es, en el forms. py   enviar los datos del capo equipo a una lista, pero lo malo de esto que cada ves que agrego un equipo devo actualizar el servidor para que tome el nuevo cambio

Comment: Acabo de ver la actualisacion de tu pregunta, pero no es necesario hacer eso, deja que Django genere los widgets. Tu modelo `DatosOperador` tiene la relación `equipo`, dicha relación tiene por defecto un **"campo de formulario"** llamado  [`ModelChoiceField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.ModelChoiceField), que a su ves tiene un **"widget"** por defecto, llamado [`Select`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/widgets/#django.forms.Select), Django se encarga de generar el widget, con su respectivo QuerySet.

Comment: Es decir NO necesitas sobrescribir los campos de formulario (como lo haces), pues Django se encargara de eso, te deberia funcionar correctamente y listarte los equipos, al generar el widget (`{{ form.equipo }}`)

Comment: Hola e seguido cada paso y no me muestra el campo equipos como una lista en el Template, solo me a funcionado como lo tengo en el form, no se si tenga que hacer algo dentro del fomrs.py o dentro de mi funcion en el model.py

Comment: En tu campo `nameequipo` (o `equipo`) en ves de `forms.ChoiceField(choices=CHOICES4, ...)`, pon este campo de formulario: `forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=DatosEquipo.objects.all())`, y dime si funciona.

Comment: Hola amigo gracias por la ayuda encontre con tu sugeriencia la siguente solucion,  nameequipo=forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=DatosEquipo.objects.order_by('ideq').values('nombreequipo').distinct(), required=True);  cuando publico en el template lo malo es que me muestra los equipos de la siguiente manera en la lisa  
{'nombreequipo': u'Equipo1'} y al momento de ingresar tiene el mismo formato y no me permite el ingreso de los equipos

Comment: No te entiendo, de ser posible actualisa tu pregunta con los detalles, para poder ayudarte con mayor facilidad.

Answer (score 1):

Hola a todos por fin lo logre la solucion era en el forms

```
nameequipo=forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=DatosEquipo.objects.order_by('ideq').values_list('nombreequipo', flat=True).distinct(),
            empty_label=None, label=None, required=True)
```

De esta forma llamo a los datos de tabla de la BD y de esta forma la publicarlo en el Template aparece en forma de lista al solo llamar

```
{{form.nameequipo}}
```

Gracias a Julio Cesar por la ayuda me permitio guiarme

Comment: En realidad eso no es necesario, Django lo hace automaticamente, pero si quieres personalisar el QuerySet (como lo hiciste), pues no es inecesario y es valido. **Ten presente eso**, por otra parte recuerda aceptar la respuesta, Saludos!! :)